# Nginx on docker - Vary: Accept-Encoding header is missing

Tags: nginx, https, docker, http

I'm serving a static website from nginx that runs on a docker container which is based on nginx:alpine base image.

My DockerFile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=angular-built app/dist/dayTwoApp /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The default.conf file:

```
server {
   listen 80;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types    text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I see the **vary : Accept-Encoding** header in the response from a served html file (see below).

**But for some reason i don't see the header in the js and css responses.**

(*) Relevant references which didn't work:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999606/enable-gzip-compression-with-nginx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637678/set-vary-accept-encoding-header-nginx

**Details of responses:**

**html file:**

[image]

**js files (also for css):**

[image]

Comment: The lack of Vary: in that response doesn't mean anything; the response indicates that the JavaScript was served from your browser's cache. Clear your cache and try again.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the reply, i see the same result when iI disable the cache.
Plus if the js/css files were served from my cache i think it should have show: (from disk cache) in the response.

Comment: It did show it was served from your browser's cache. That's what status 304 means. If you actually cleared your cache, then post the response headers from such a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding to your nginx configuration:

```
gzip_proxied any
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;
```

(Only responses with the “text/html” type are [always compressed](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_vary).)

Comment: Very small files might also be "skipped" by default... you can set `gzip_min_length` to be sure of the setting, and then test with a large file to be sure it's big enough to trigger the gzip compression: https://www.thedotproduct.org/posts/nginx-vary-header-handling.html